# How to normalize mass units (Kilogram and LBS) properly into a database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, normalization

I am working on a workout web app and i want to offer users the possibility to go back and forth between Kilogram and LBS for their workout log.

The app offers 0.25 steps, which means you can log 25.0, 25.25, 25.5 and 25.75 for both Kilogram and LBS.

What is the right way to normalize the weight data in the database field? I am thinking about normalizing it into grams and then converting from their into KG or LBS.

Comment: The max weight might affect your decision...

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I am not sure why it would. What is the difference between normalizing 30 or 600 kilogram/lbs into grams?

Comment: Max number size.  `1200 lbs`, which is a rare-but-not-unheard-of weight, comes out to `544311`.  This is larger than the 32767 signed int value and thus, will affect the back-end data storage choices.

Comment: According to the Posgresql Docs, +32767 would be the limit of a `small int`, whereas `integer` would be at +2147483647. Am i missing something? I am using Rails and Postgres, if that makes any difference.

Comment: There is no right way to do the wrong thing.  If you force the user to round at such a coarse level which is unit-dependent on units with no good common factor when storing the data, then you can't let them change that unit willy nilly or it will make a hash of the stored numbers.  But that is not a database issue.

Comment: @jjanes You are saying there is no good way to convert back and forth? I don't really expect someone to change their unit for logging. Where i need it is when people share a workout log and the person viewing it should be able two switch to their unit. So the next best thing would be enough i think

Comment: @drale2k There is no good way to store 113 grams (about 1/4 pound) and then display it back rounded to the nearest 250 grams.  But if you are already willing to deal with that on the display side, there is no problem in saving both sources in integer grams.  But since you need to deal rounding anyway (113 grams is not exactly 1/4 pound), there is no real point in forcing the grams to be integer rather than float.  There are performance benefits, but probably not meaningful ones.

Comment: Would i be better off with only 0.5 steps instead of 0.25 ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you will find [weight gem](https://github.com/shemerey/weight#configuration) itself or it's source code useful. It's purpose is

> to provide convenient way to work with weight in a different unit
>   systems.

As for storing mass units in a DB you could choose any default unit (KG or LBS) and apply it as decimal field in Rails migration.

Answer (score -1):

For unit conversion, there are several available gems, such as `sy`:

```
# after performing gem install sy
require 'sy/imperial'

weights = [ 4.2.kg, 4.3.kg, 4.2.lb, 4.3.lb ]
weights_in_grams = weights.map { |w| w.in :gram }
in_lbs = weights_in_grams.map { |w| w.gram.in :pound } # .in :lb works as well
in_kg = weights_in_grams.map { |w| w.gram.in :kilogram }
```